# Assisted hardware virtualization on a Sony Vaio

Tags: virtualization

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-NR11Z/S, which has support for assisted hardware virtualization but Sony decided not to put this option in the BIOS menu. Is there any tool or any other way which would allow me to enable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason best known to themselves Sony disabled this in their BIOSes, however, by flashing the appropriate BIOS, you can reenable it, I did so with a VGN-C2S without any problems.

Try this: http://www.techtangerine.com/2010/05/19/enabling-hardware-virtualization-on-a-sony-vaio-vgn-cr320-laptop-an-experience/

A similar approach worked for me, you have to manually swap the relevant bit in the BIOS, and find the right bit to swap, there are lists out there that have been compiled for the different machines and the various BIOSes.  I discovered that the machine doesn't seem to matter, just check which BIOS you currently have installed and look that up in the list for the correct bit to swap.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a known way round it other than to use alternate virtualisation products such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) which do not rely on the VT-bit (well at least it didn't when I last looked a couple of years ago, remember a message saying you **shouldn't** use it).

There are many people complaining about this for some time. [Here is just one comment thread](http://forums.theregister.co.uk/forum/1/2009/08/06/sony_vaio_virtualization_disabled/) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your particular model, but we just had this issue with a Sony Vaio Touchscreen which needed to be able to run XP Compatibility mode under Win 7 Ultimate.  The solution was to download and install the revised BIOS from Sony's website.  It looks like Sony has gotten enough backlash, that they are starting to put BIOS updates on their site for most models.